# Unity, rotating the camera with the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, camera, rotation

I have managed to write the script which rotates the camera from the position of the mouse. It is

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotatingTheCamera
{
        [SerializeField] private float sensitivityVert;
        [SerializeField] private float sensitivityHor;
        [SerializeField] private float minimumVert;
        [SerializeField] private float maximumVert;
        private float _rotationX = 0;

        private void Update()
        {
                if (Time.timeScale == 1)
                {
                        _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
                        _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
                        float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor;
                        float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + delta;
                        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
                }
        }
}
```

I don't know how to rotate the camera basing on the pressing the left button of the mouse (like dragging, but rotating). Is it even possible without that "New Input System"? I can't use it now (I am not a sorcerer) And is there any dependancy on Time.deltaTime?

UPD:  ideone.com/pOS2gB is working

Comment: What is the outcome you want from your code? Are you asking how to detect if the mouse button is being held down? It's unclear what your objective is.

Comment: I want to run this code only if the mouse button is held down. But "if (Time.timeScale == 1 && GetMouseButtonDown(0))" dosn't do what I want, it just decreases sensitivity.

Comment: wouldn't it be `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It is the same as Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)

Comment: I think I have found the solution. https://ideone.com/pOS2gB